# why we can move out String from struct field, but can't move via struct reference and can't move String from vec in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and I find some behavior in Rust is not intuitive

say we have the code below:

```rust
struct User {
    name: String,
    email:String
}


fn main() {
    let some_vec = vec![String::from("value1"),String::from("value2")];
    
    let _v = some_vec[0];
    
    let user = User {
        name:String::from("name"),
        email:String::from("email")
    };
    
    let user_ref = &user;
    
    let _name = user_ref.name;
    
    let _email = user.email;
}
```

and the compiler complains that :

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<String>`
  --> src/main.rs:19:14
   |
19 |     let _v = some_vec[0];
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
help: consider borrowing here
   |
19 |     let _v = &some_vec[0];
   |              +

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `user_ref.name` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:28:17
   |
28 |     let _name = user_ref.name;
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `user_ref.name` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
help: consider borrowing here
   |
28 |     let _name = &user_ref.name;
   |                 +
```

1. I think `Vec` and `Struct` are alike in grouping value together.
   so I thought if we can't move String from vec via index, we can't move String from struct field, either. but there is no error in  `let _email = user.email;`
2. I know we can't move out of a reference,like this:

```
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let v_ref: &Vec<i32> = &v;
    let v2 = *v_ref;// move occurs because `*v_ref` has type `Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

so the code `let _name = user_ref.name` is actually `let _name = (*user_ref).name` after the compiler dereference automatically ？ it is a similar way to move out of a reference like the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think Vec and Struct are alike in grouping value together.

They are not, because a "struct" is "transparent" to the compiler, as in the compiler is able to sus out different fields of a struct, that is not the case with indexing `vec`, which is an opaque operation. That is why you can uniquely borrow different fields of a struct, but not different indices of a vec.

> there is no error in  `let _email = user.email;`

That's because it's performing a [partial move](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/move/partial_move.html) out of the struct, afterwards you can neither pass around `user` itself as a unit (e.g. as a parameter to a function):

> error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `user`

nor access `user.email`:

> error[E0382]: use of moved value: `user.email`

you can only access the *other* fields of the structure.

> so the code let _name = user_ref.name is actually `let _name = (*user_ref).name` after the compiler dereference automatically ？

That is what [automatic dereference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/field-expr.html#automatic-dereferencing) means, yes. It dereferences, automatically.

Comment: so `let _name = (*user_ref).name` is still a way of move out of a reference? I thought `let _user = *user_ref`   meet the conditions (I mean , directly) but I never thought about `(*user_ref).name`

Comment: Well it's a way to try, but unless `name` is `Copy` it's not going to work.